# How to export phone usage time data to json/csv/sql/txt raw form?

Tags: notifications, digital-wellbeing

There are many apps like Google's Digital Wellbeing and another famous app called Action Dash.

These apps show your data about how many times the phone unlocked, per-app usage stats, no of times an app launched, no of notification etc.

How can I get all these data in raw format from my android phone?

I basically want to use python to perform some analysis on these data.

Answer (score 1):

There are some apps in the play store that let you see more.

1. [App Usage - Manage/Track Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.uninstaller) This app lets you export the data.
2. [Action Dash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actiondash.playstore) This has a great amount of data that is being analyzed in the app. (This makes me think that the data is stored somewhere).

Take a look at the folders and files in "/data/data/com.google.android.apps.wellbeing" you may find something useful files there. There are some files there that look promising. You will need to be rooted to access this folder.

Comment: Action dash allows you to backup data, the files are sqlite database, but inside content is in binary form. Not readable . In the App Usage app the CSV data of every single day is not available. If I do export from time A to time B, it gives the total usage of apps during that time period, not every single day

Comment: What about the files data/data/com.google.android.apps.wellbeing ?

Comment: @aahnik how do you export data in ActionDash?